# Zipkin for Java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, zipkin, brave

I have Java application that is sending requests to Spring Boot applications. I have implemented zipkin+sleuth on the Spring Boot applications and get traces. Now I want to implement zipkin on the java application and to collect the traces. How to implement that? I need to use brave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have to use Brave. In fact, Spring cloud sleuth (V2) uses Brave under the hood. Check the brave web-mvc example to get started.

https://github.com/openzipkin/brave-webmvc-example

Comment: Thank you about the information, but I think that the implementation in Java application is completely different from this example.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your java application? There are instrumentations available for most of the popular libraries within brave. I will try to direct you to the right one.

Comment: Currently I have problem with two things with brave: Java application that is sending request to CXF application that is laying in Service Mix (SOAP based). The second problem is this one: https://github.com/jacklund/mqttKafkaBridge/blob/master/src/main/java/com/m2mci/mqttKafkaBridge/Bridge.